# How to make the foreground and background colors of a button in Tkinter random

Tags: python, tkinter

and im trying to make a label colors random i tried the code on the bottom, but it doesnt work. The colors come out as red green blue yellw orange white cyan purple. How do I make it appear as single colors?

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'white', 'cyan', 'purple']
    class Example(Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")

            self.parent = parent

            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):

            self.parent.title("Credits")

            self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
            label1 = Label(self, text="Code by blaba, fg=colors, bg=colors)
            label1.pack()
            label2 = Label(self, text="Idea by noctize", fg=colors, bg=colors)
            label2.pack()
            label3 = Label(self, text="Packed using py2exe", fg=colors, bg=colors)
            label3.pack()
            colorbutton = Button


            quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit",
                command=self.quit)
            quitButton.place(x=50, y=70)


    def main():

        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
        app = Example(root)
        root.mainloop()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

how come it wont work?

Comment: why colorbutton when you are not using it...its not even being displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `colors` is a *list of colors*, not a color name.

You can use `random.choice` to pick up random colors, like this:

```
import random

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'white', 'cyan', 'purple']
#your class declaration, __init__ declaration and more
def initUI(self):
        randomized = []
        for i in range(3):
            #this will pick three of the colors to be the color
            randomized.append(random.choice(colors))

        self.parent.title("Credits")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        label1 = Label(self, text="Code by blaba", fg=randomized[0], bg=randomized[0])
        label1.pack()
        label2 = Label(self, text="Idea by noctize", fg=randomized[1], bg=randomized[1])
        label2.pack()
        label3 = Label(self, text="Packed using py2exe", fg=randomized[2], bg=randomized[2]
        label3.pack()
        colorbutton = Button
```

Also, i fixed a typo in the `label1` declaration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: getting something like:"global name 'colors' is not defined

Comment: Have you defined the variable?

Comment: Just replace the code of `initUI`, except for the `quitButton` part.

Comment: I have tried it, but im still getting some errors The error:http://s17.postimg.org/dl4zchxbj/Untitled.jpg The code:http://pastebin.com/9AVgkshc (read the tkinter part)

Comment: Fixed it. You have to put the colors list within the initui. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
de=("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
re=("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
we=("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
ge="#"
color=ge+de+re+we
```

and in tkinter  put

```
fill=color
```

easy
you can also make

```
fill="#"+("%06x"%random.randint(0,16777215))
```